# ValueError converting to string after Splitlines()

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion

I'm trying to take some data from an online CSV file and make a table from it. 
I use splitlines() to isolate each bit of data but I keep getting a ValueError:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Year'
```

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

url = "https://raw.github.com/datasets/gdp/master/data/gdp.csv"
webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
dataList = []
NewTable = []
print('done')
for row in datareader:
    ##print(row)
    countryName, countryCode, Year, Value= row
    print(Year)
    Year = int(Year)
    ##Value = float(Value)
    rowTuple = countryName, countryCode, Year, Value
    dataList.append(rowTuple)
```

When I uncomment "print(Year)" I get a list of integers. All numbers between 1960-2012 and I can't figure out why it won't accept the conversion from string to integer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your first row in the CSV is a header row, not a data row:

```
Country Name,Country Code,Year,Value
```

Skip it with:

```
datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines())
next(datareader, None)  # skip the header
```

You could use the [`io.TextIOWrapper()` object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to have the webpage decoded from UTF-8 for you:

```
import io

webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
datareader = csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(webpage, 'utf-8'))
next(datareader, None)  # skip the header
```

Comment: You could suggest using DictReader too.